# Will xubuntu and lubuntu give better performance for software development tools

Tags: xubuntu, lubuntu, performance

I have tried xubuntu and lubuntu and found battery sacing distro. Will these distros provide me enough performance for using software development tools like eclipse, netbeans, tomcats, xampp etc

Thank you

Comment: They don't necessarily boost performance, they only use less resources, meaning the system can perform faster. If you have a low-spec computer, heavy programs might work better in Lubuntu or Xubuntu, but not necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

xUbuntu, lUbuntu and any other official release based on Ubuntu share the same pool of repositories. It is just that all of them use a different desktop and use different default applications.

If you need to run any of these systems you probably have a system that is not as powerful as needed to run Ubuntu. But that does not stop you from picking Eclipse, Netbeans, Tomcat to install if you do not like the default or preferred applications for that system. They will work. Some will install a lot of dependencies you would not have to install otherwise but it is possible. The applications made for your system should be preferred over the other applications since those are optimized for that system. Kate (editor) works best on kUbuntu, works on Ubuntu but you really should use gEdit.

The only one I would avoid is Xampp. Our native lamp stack (installed with `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`) is far superior, better documented and works out of the box.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The main reason I want to go for lubuntu or xubuntu is power concern. I have linux mint installed which consumes a lot of battery power, gives only 2 hours battery whereas xubuntu gave 3 hours. I am a software developer. So I want to know whether these two low resource consuming linux distro will hang or not when I use heavy programs